# What is meaning of @ at prometheus metric value

Tags: prometheus

Sometimes I can see metric values containing `@` sign. this sign seems to appear when I use `range vector` `[]`.

What is the meaning of `@` sign?

For example, `1 @1516211886.667`.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a convention to represent the timestamp of the sample. The value is unixtime in seconds.